# Unable to bind to 0.0.0.0:8333 on this computer. Bitcoin is probably already running

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, linux, error

I installed bitcoin-qt and my wallet was all synced, everything working as it should. I sighed up for slush's pool and was trying to connect the 2 and I think I may have clicked the box to run SOCKS proxy (if I am remembering right)  Now my wallet will not show up on my desktop and when I click the icon I get 2 errors:

1. Unable to bind to 0.0.0.0:8333 on this computer. Bitcoin is probably already running.
2. Failed to listen on any port. Use -listen=0 if you want this.

I am running Fedora 18.  I tried to uninstall/reinstall and ended up with the same issue, i'm assuming I did not uninstall ALL of the initial package/program.

Can someone help PLEASE!!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that betcoind is not running?

```
Bitcoin is probably already running.
```

You can try to restart your computer...

Comment: how to change the port to 8334?